# Synonyms: [email-server], [mail-server], [mailserver]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

These 4 tags should be made synonyms:

- [email-server](/questions/tagged/email-server)
- [mail-server](/questions/tagged/mail-server)
- [mailserver](/questions/tagged/mailserver)

I think [mail-server](/questions/tagged/mail-server) should be the master tag, even though [mailserver](/questions/tagged/mailserver) is more popular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Results:**

- [mail-server](/questions/tagged/mail-server) ← [mailserver](/questions/tagged/mailserver) (merge)
- [mail-server](/questions/tagged/mail-server) ← [email-server](/questions/tagged/email-server) (merge, synonym created)