# Tag merge request: [mailserver] and [mail-server]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Synonyms: [email-server], [emailserver], [mail-server], [mailserver]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114628/synonyms-email-server-emailserver-mail-server-mailserver)

[mailserver](/questions/tagged/mailserver) and [mail-server](/questions/tagged/mail-server) should be merged. For obvious reasons :)

Comment: There are also email variants.  I posted about this a few months ago but no one actually did it. See here: [Synonyms: email-server, emailserver, mail-server, mailserver](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114628/172958)